# Dapper sqlmapperextensions automatically adds "s" to tablename?

Tags: c#, dapper

This is my first experience with **Dapper.Contrib** (latest version from Nuget) and it's a strange situation:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    var product = cn.Get<Product>(1);
}
```

On SqlMapperExtensions, it raises the error `Invalid object name 'Products'`:

```
public static T Get<T>(this IDbConnection connection,
                       dynamic id, 
                       IDbTransaction transaction = null, 
                       int? commandTimeout = null) where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    string sql;
    if (!GetQueries.TryGetValue(type.TypeHandle, out sql))
}
```

The database receives the command `select * from Products where Id = @id` which is wrong.

### Why does it append `s` to Product?

I've tried with other tables and get the same result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that it's written this way, you can check the **[source code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L273)**

Or more specifically:

```
private static string GetTableName(Type type)
{
    //.... codes

    if (TableNameMapper != null)
    {
        name = TableNameMapper(type);
    }
    else
    {
        var tableAttr = //.... lookup attribute
        if (tableAttr != null)
            name = tableAttr.Name;
        else
        {
            name = type.Name + "s";
            if (type.IsInterface() && name.StartsWith("I"))
                    name = name.Substring(1);
        }
    }
```

If you want to use the literal type name you can easily configure this.

```
SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) => {
    //use exact name
    return type.Name;
};
```

Answer (score 19):

It is desgined this way. You can override the default behavior by decorating your **POCO classes** with `Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.TableAttribute`.

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is great, although it is not a good practice to have Dapper dependency on an assembly of POCO
Dapper is happy if you do
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
instead of using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions