# Dapper use singular table name

Tags: c#, dapper

I experimented with Dapper and Dapper.Contrib. I have the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

It is beeing mapped to the table "`Customers`" which is pluralized. Is there a simple way to make Dapper use singular table names for all tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dapper sqlmapperextensions automatically adds "s" to tablename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341079/dapper-sqlmapperextensions-automatically-adds-s-to-tablename)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Dapper.Contrib supports the `Table` attribute. Use it to manually specify the name of the table that an entity uses. See the [docs](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib#special-attributes) for further information.

Alternatively there is a static delegate on `SqlMapperExtensions` called [`TableNameMapper`](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib/blob/main/src/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L53). You can replace this with an implementation that performs the pluralization. [PluralizationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the framework can help you here.

It is used as follows:

```
SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) => {
    // do something here to pluralize the name of the type
    return type.Name;
};
```

Comment: I tried to implement a function using that delegate, but no luck. Could you please give more details with an example of how to use `SqlMapperExtensions`? Especially on `// do something here to pluralize the name of the type` part, assuming that we have POCO class Student, which is pluralized by Dapper and becomes Students.
Also, I have created a question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60600746/how-to-properly-singularize-table-names-with-dapper-contrib)

Comment: the docs link above is broken.  Correct docs link for [specialized attributes](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib#special-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Table' data annotation attribute on your entity class as follows:

```
[Table("Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```