# How to properly "Singularize" table names with Dapper.Contrib?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper, dapper-contrib

I have a .Net Core 3.1 Console application.

In SQL Server database I have tables with singular names, the same as my POCO classes, which is convenient for matching and maintaining.

For Insert, Update and Delete operations I want to use `Dapper.Contrib` library. But when I run Insert function Dapper pluralize table names in generated SQL queries.

SQL table "Student":

```
CREATE TABLE Student
    StudentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50)
```

C# code

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var students = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student { StudentId = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"},
                new Student { StudentId = 2, FirstName = "Tony", LastName = "Montana"}
            }

        long result;
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                        result = cn.Insert(students);
            }
    }
}
```

On output I get an exception:

> Invalid object name 'Students'.

I surfed around to find a solution, but couldn't find a working example. In general there two kinds of recommendations:

1. **Use data annotations**. This one is not suitable for me, as there are a lot of POCO objects created automatically from a database using `Scaffold-DbContext`. During the development process, I make changes in database and then re-create POCOs again. This operation deletes all changes made in generated POCO classes.
2. Use of `SqlMapperExtensions` delegate:

   `SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) => {
       // do something here to pluralize the name of the type
       return type.Name;
   };`

I don't know how to properly use this delegate, and where to place it.
I experimented a while, but I am sure that I don't use it properly:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
            SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) =>
            {
                type.Name.Remove(type.Name.Length - 1, 1);
                return type.Name;
            };
            result = cn.Insert(students);
    }
```

On this line of code `type.Name.Remove(type.Name.Length - 1, 1);` I tried to implement a function which cuts-off the last letter in the name of the type `Student`, assuming that Dapper adds the last letter "s" to the name of the class, and I remove it in my implementation.
Example: `Student => Students => Student(s) => Student`.

Long story short - I couldn't find a solution of how to implement a function that will "singularize" my table names.

How should I use `SqlMapperExtensions` or maybe there is another approach which may "singularize" table names without making changes in POCO classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation has a couple of problems but, because you're essentially returning `type.Name`, it should be returning the name of your type (in this case `Student`).

First let's address the problems with your current implementation of `TableNameMapper`;

1. You only need to set the delegate once. You can do this somewhere like the `ConfigureServices` of your `Startup` class. Right now you're setting it everytime you open your connection.
2. Your implementation executes `type.Name.Remove(type.Name.Length - 1, 1);` but you're not assigning the result of the operation to a variable. Even if you had assigned the result you're just returning `type.Name` anyway.

I ran the code you have above and it works correctly for me in LINQPad. I'd suggest adding a breakpoint in your debugger on the `return type.Name;` line of your delegate. If you need a hand debugging then take a look at the [Visual Studio debugging documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour). Check what `type.Name` actually is and go from there.

Here's the code I ran verbatim:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) => type.Name;

        var students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student { StudentId = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
            new Student { StudentId = 2, FirstName = "Tony", LastName = "Montana" }
        };

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Insert(students);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
[Table("student")]
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the way

Comment: This should have been the answer, and by default it should not add s to the table, that is a bad implementation

Comment: @Maccurt yes and in my case "activity" is assumed to be "activitys" by default, so even better reason not to guess plurals